# The distribution of a posterior predictive p-value under certain assumptions

Tags: bayesian, p-value, posterior, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I am wondering if anyone can check my understanding of the following passage concerning posterior predictive p-values in the textbook "[Bayesian Data Analysis 3rd Edition](https://amzn.to/2M0Ap7B)" on page 151:

> In the special case that the parameters $\theta$ are known (or
>   estimated to a very high precision) or in which the test statistic
>   $T(y)$ is ancillary (that is, if it depends only on observed data and
>   if its distribution is independent of the parameters of the model)
>   with a continuous distribution, the posterior predictive p-value
>   $P(T(y^{\text{rep}}) > T(y) \mid y)$ has a distribution that is uniform
>   if the model is true.

I suspect this is something akin to what is called the "CDF transformation" where a random variable $X$ is transformed by plugging it into its own CDF. In other words, if $X$ has a cdf $F_X( \cdot)$, then the random variable $F_X(X)$ is uniformly distributed. And correct me if this is wrong, but another way to write this is $P(X \le x \mid \tilde{X} = x)$ where $\tilde{X}$ is just another iid copy of $X$.

So I guess if we can show that

- $T(y^{\text{rep}}) \mid y$ and
- $T(y) \mid \theta$

are distributed in the same way, that this implies

$$
P(T(y^{\text{rep}}) > T(y) \mid y) = 1 - F(T(y))
$$

where $F$ is the CDF of both of those random variables. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, as a function of the rv $Y$, in this special case, $\mathbb{P}(T(Y^{\text{rep}}) > T(Y) \mid Y)$ is distributed as a Uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Xi'an for the confirmation. The authors are saying that when 
$$
P(T(y^{\text{rep}}) > T(y) \mid y) = P(T(y^{\text{rep}}) > T(y) \mid \theta, y)
$$
then the reasoning of the CDF transformation mentioned above implies that these are uniformly distributed on the unit interval.

I was planning on asking about the next paragraph as well, but I think I understand it now.

> More generally, when posterior uncertainty in $\theta$ propagates to
>   the distribution of $T(y \mid \theta)$, the distribution of the
>   p-value is more likely to be near $.5$ than near $0$ or $1$. (To be
>   more precise, the sampling distribution of the p-value has been shown
>   to be 'stochastically less variable' than uniform.)

Perhaps by "stochastically less variable" they mean convex-ordered. If this is the case, it's straightforward to show, using Jensen's inequality, that conditional probabilities are convex-ordered when one conditions on less than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The null hypotheis $H_0$ of the test is the likelihood $f(Y|\theta)$ is right. You also assume you prior $\pi(\theta)$ is "right".

The first condition "if it depends only on observed data" is saying:
$T(Y)$ cannot depend on $\theta$, which is the unknown parameters in the likelihood $f(Y|\theta)$.

The second condition "its distribution is independent of the parameters of the model" is as follows.
Let $Y^{obs}$ be your observed data. Under $H_0$, there is a density for $Y^{obs}$, which is $\int f(Y^{obs}|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta$, and a density for $T(Y^{obs})$. Let's call this density as $g(T(Y^{obs}))$. What you want is $g(T(Y^{obs}))$ does not depend on $\theta$.

That being said, the notation you used "$T(y)|\theta$" is not entirely right as we do not condition on a $\theta$ but integrate it out from $\int f(Y^{obs}|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta$.

Regarding your follow-up question, the practical insight of both paragraphs is, if you couldn't a $T(Y)$ that can test the specific feature of interest and satisfies the above two conditions simultaneously, the posterior predictive p-value you will get does not follow uniform(0,1) but a dome-shaped density.

This non-uniform issue is not regarded as an issue by Gelman himself

[http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/ppc_understand3.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/ppc_understand3.pdf)

but a number of statisticians find it unsatisfying as this condition is a key for hypothesis testing, e.g,

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2000.10474310
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947314001522